# fcbkcomplete, how to obtain all the values after adding or updating the Input

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fcbkcomplete

I'm interested in using [fcbkcomplete](http://www.emposha.com/demo/fcbkcomplete/), which has:

- `onselect` – fire event on item select.
- `onremove` – fire event on item remove

What I'd like to happen for those two events is to alert a list of the IDs/values of the items in the input box.

Can you help me understand how to get these values?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the plugin is tied to the actual `select` element, not the `option` elements inside, you should be able to write a function that just alerts out all option details of the contained options of the parent select. Maybe something like:

```
$("#select").fcbkcomplete({
       onselect: function() {
           var optionList;
           $("option",this).each(function() {
               optionList += $(this).attr("id") + " : " + $(this).val() + "\n";
           });
           alert(optionList);
       }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Can you help me understand what the core of this is supposed to be doing? thxs

Comment: Try it now. I made a false assumption that `this.id()` would return the id, which it doesn't. I fixed that. What it's doing is going through every option element in the select element you have the add on set to and adding "id : value" to a string and then altering that string at the end of the loop.

Comment: Let me know if that fixed it, btw.

Comment: @Anthony - what is the ".=" in the line: optionList .= ??

Comment: @Anthony - this gives me the results of EVERY select on my page.. not just the ones in this

Comment: @ooo .= is from PHP and probably a typo, replace it with +=

Comment: @Chris S - thanks. this code above still gets EVERY select box on the page and not just the one with the fcbkcomplete so i am not sure why the answer was selected as correct.  My guess is that in this example, this was the only select on the page.  that being said, its not really the correct answer.

Comment: @ooo have you tried out tag-it? http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tag-it it's a lot less fiddly

Answer (score 0):

Checks if an item exists in the DB in this case a user.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#users").fcbkcomplete({
        json_url: "yoururl.php",
        cache: false,
        filter_case: false,
        filter_hide: true,
        complete_text:"'.get_lang('StartToType').'",
        firstselected: true,
        onselect:"check_users",   //<----- important
        filter_selected: true,
        newel: true
    });
});
```

Hewe we check if users exists in the DB

```
function check_users() {
    //selecting only "selected" users
    $("#users option:selected").each(function() {
        var user_id = $(this).val();        
        if (user_id != "" ) {            
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "my_other_url_to_check_users.php", 
                data: "user_id="+user_id,
                success: function(return_value) {
                    if (return_value == 0 ) {
                        alert("UserDoesNotExist");                        
                    }                    
                },            
            });                
        }        
    });
}
```